# Is it possible to access microsoft graph using custom audience?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have an API that uses Azure AD to provide access to resources. It has one scope `api://{client_id}/Api.Read` and following API permissions:
User.Read.All,
User.Read.

When I receive an access token from the AD it has only one aud - {client_id} and when I try to access Microsoft graph (e.g. `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me`) I get "Access token validation failure. Invalid audience." response as expected.

My question is - Is it possible to access both graph API and my API using one token and how do it?

Comment: You need to generate separate tokens for each API. Using same token for both API's is not possible.

Comment: @Sridevi ok, thank you. Maybe you know - is it possible to ask for authentication ones but get two tokens for different scopes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am exchanging current token to a "proper" token using on-behalf-of call: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow

Basically, you just make the following call (copied from the link above):

```
POST /oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1
Host: login.microsoftonline.com/<YOUR_TENANT>
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer
&requested_token_use=on_behalf_of
&client_id=<YOUR_CLIENT_ID>
&client_secret=<YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET>
&assertion=<YOUR_CURRENT_TOKEN>
&scope=<YOUR_NEW_SCOPES>
```

The response contains the new token to access the resources that are requested in the scopes. My scenario is not exactly yours, but I think this should work for your case as well. You need to make this call server-side.

This assumes that the user has already consented that your app is okay to use <YOUR_NEW_SCOPES>, or otherwise this call will result in "interaction_required" or "invalid_grant" error (something like this, don't remember the exact error name) that basically means you need to raise UI prompt for the user to agree to the new scopes (how to do that is another question)

Comment: Thank you a lot! I will try this approach and return back with a feedback

Comment: I tried it out and unfortunately faced CORS. Is it possible to do this request from the client side?

Comment: No it is not possible to exchange token client side like that as far as I know (for security reasons: you need to specify client secret that is only available server side)